# App getting Crashed while installing it for the first time in React Native

Tags: react-native, axios, react-android

`ERROR  TypeError: Restricted in strict mode, js engine: hermes` is getting thrown when trying to import `Axios` for network request in react native application.  The error gets removed when i'm trying to remove the import statement from the below code.

`api.js`

```
import axios from "axios";

    export default axios.create({
    
        baseURL:"https://.com/v3/test",
        headers:{
            Authorization:'Bearer fsdfsfsd'
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to downgrade the axios version.

```
yarn remove axios
yarn add axios@0.27.2
```

If it is not getting listed from node modules when trying to import Axios, import the package as follows:

```
const axios = require('axios')
```

Comment: I have used npm install axios. yarn is not working for me.

Comment: Use "npm uninstall axios" to remove the previous package and "npm install axios@0.27.2" to install the new package

Comment: I have tried  using the same , but when trying to import `axios`, it is not getting listed from node modules.

Comment: Can you see the axios folder in node_modules?

Comment: yea, it is there

Comment: then try to import it as "const axios = require('axios')"

Comment: it is working fine now.